# Use the same WebSocket to push messages to a client

Tags: concurrency, websocket

I'm starting with WebSockets, I already built a chat web-application as an exercise and it went something like this:
Every user has an opened websocket connection at their arrival to the chat-room, and when new messages are available, they're simply pushed to each user. The different messages are then displayed using javaScript.

Now, I'm trying to push the exercise a bit further by creating a one-on-one chat. Basically, there will no longer be a unique chat-room but private chat conversations. A user should be able to talk to different people from the same page. (Something like Google chat or Facebook chat).
After thinking about ways to do so, I came down to two solutions:

- Open multiple websocket connections. (if possible)
- Use the same connection to handle all opened conversations. Basically, each message that is pushed to the client will carry a field saying to which conversation it belongs, a javaScript will then handle the display of each message under the right conversation.

To me, the second solution seems better than the first. So, my questions are:

```
1- Will this solution have any performance problems? (Lost messages...)
2- Is there any other-better way of doing this?
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to go depends (IMHO) on what framework you are using to do this communication.
I (as you) would go for multiplexing (second option) where you use one connection to handle all communication.

I assume that your framework of choice supports publish/subscribe and multiplexing?

I can provide you with a simple example if you like.

Regards
Uffe, Team XSockets